# Servicestack convert IServiceCollection into Funq entries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, servicestack

Does the servicestack.core package contain a https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#replacing-the-default-services-container implementation?

To convert IServiceCollection to Funq container registrations? something like this?

```
        var container = new Container();
        services.Each(x =>
        {
            if (x.ImplementationType != null)
                container.Register(x.ImplementationInstance, x.ServiceType);
            else if (x.ImplementationFactory != null)
                container.RegisterFn(x.ServiceType, x.ImplementationFactory);
            else
                container.RegisterAutoWiredType(x.ServiceType, x.ImplementationType, x.Lifetime == ServiceLifetime.Singleton ? ReuseScope.Container : x.Lifetime == ServiceLifetime.Scoped ? ReuseScope.Request : ReuseScope.None);

        });

        public static Container RegisterFn(this Container container, Type serviceType, Func<IServiceProvider, object> factory)
        {

            typeof(FunqExtensions).GetMethodInfos().First(x =>x.Name == "Register").MakeGenericMethod(serviceType).Invoke(null, new object[]{ container, factory});
            return container;
        }

        private static Container Register<T>(this Container container, Func<IServiceProvider, object> registrationFactory)
        {
            container.Register<T>(null, c => (T) registrationFactory(c));
            return container;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

No Funq's not intended to replace .NET Core's IoC but any [dependencies registered in .NET Core's IoC are also available to ServiceStack](http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#net-core-container-adapter).

Comment: why not? doesn't it perfectly make sense to use just funq as an ioc container and insert the core registrations in there, instead of having 2 containers at runtine and trying to resolve them in both?

Comment: @JoelHarkes It makes sense to use .NET Core's built-in IOC for .NET Core which it was designed to support and ServiceStack built-in Funq IOC for ServiceStack. It's logical that any dependencies registered in .NET Core Startup is available to both .NET Core and ServiceStack and that any dependencies registered in ServiceStack is only available to ServiceStack as it's done now. So when you want registrations available globally register them in .NET Core Startup.

Comment: But this could lead to massive confusion. say i make a library with extension method to be included in .netCore's IOC but i overwrite one of the classes myself: I HAVE to define tis in the netCores ioc container (otherwise it is not found) and i CANT use dependencies i specify in the funq container, since it only goes one way.

Comment: It's not intuitive to assume dependencies registered in a different framework, at a different location using a different IOC can be confused for the same IOC. There shouldn't be any expectation the outer .NET Core IOC has access to dependencies registered in an internal frameworks IOC. If you want dependencies registered available everywhere just use .NET Cores IOC.

Comment: In our code its simply 1 application, not: 1 framework or the other. the `other framework` was simple necessary for running on dotnet core. and of course for us we would like to have one place to define ioc registrations, otherwise it gets very confusing. so simply put, you suggest to specify everything in netcore's IServiceCollection, to avoid this issue.